# padding между RadioButton text и RadioButton drawable (LEFT и RIGHT)

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте.

Screenshot: https://vk.cc/5Dbwum

Как можно отодвинуть текст от иконки? И можно ещё как-то сменить размер drawableLeft?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.boss.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/select_language"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/select_ru"
            android:id="@+id/select_ru"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Russia"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:background="#396250" />

        <RadioButton
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/select_uk"
            android:id="@+id/select_uk"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="United Kingdom"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:background="#396250" />

        <RadioButton
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/select_us"
            android:id="@+id/select_us"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="USA"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:background="#396250" />
    </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно выдаче гугла на запрос

> [android drawableleft padding](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20drawableleft%20padding)

и первой ссылке на [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3337553/3212712) вам нужен аттрибут

```
android:drawablePadding
```